# Cant use correctly @media in css

Tags: css

I started my first site from making mobile version. After that, i tried to add @media screen and (min-width: 500px) for desktops, but after that my mobile site looks like desktop. I don't understand why and don't know how to fix it. I kept mozilla's tutorials and that's it.

```
/* CSS */
        body{
            background-color: yellow;
            display: flex;
            margin: 1em;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
        }
        
        html{
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        header{
            order: 0;
            background-color: black;
            color:blanchedalmond;
            font-size: 3em;
            padding: 0.5em 1em;
            border-radius: 1em;
            
        }
       
       
    
      
       
            
        
        header  nav{
            
            border-top: 1px solid #999;
            margin-top: 0;
        }
        header ul{
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        ...............
        @media screen and (min-width: 500px) 
        {header{
            display: flex; /* separate the nav and title */
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center; 
            font-size: 1em;
            width: 100%;
        }
        header ul {
            display: flex; /* mav navigation display using flexbox */
            }

        header li {
            margin: 0; /*remove the margin used in the mobile design */
        }
        header nav{
            border:0;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for mobile version.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px)
```

and then the rest of your code will apply for desktop-version

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: kk i somehow solve how to use min-width. I used em for width, but idk why do >62em change media-queray? I used only 3 em, 1em, 0.5 for my page

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make mobile first website you should
declare a max-width media-queray first at the above code and then the rest of your code will be applied to the desktop version

if you want to understand how both of them works
read below

[Media Queries Demystified: CSS Min-Width and Max-Width](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width/)

Comment: selam , i somehow solve how to use min-width. I used em for width, but idk why do >62em change media-queray? I used only 3 em, 1em, 0.5 for my page